# Having trouble with 0 height div, but no floats. What can I do?

Tags: css, html, layout

http://www.walkerspencer.com/chrhsweb/max

So I'm currently working on a high school project, and I'm completely stumped. One of my divs, article, isn't behaving how I'd like it to. It has a height of 0. Now, after a lot of googling and research, it seemed like this was a common issue... for containers which contained floating elements. My article contains no floating divs. I even tried removing float from the css for my #buttons div, and it had no effect. I've also tried most of the suggested float fixes: the clearfix method, clear:both. At this point, I just need an outside opinion. I couldn't find any major errors in my code (besides a general disorganization and misuse of semantic elements). The intended behavior is that sections scale while maintaining a 16:9 ratio as the browser resizes, and have a black transparent background that fills the entire article. I could also apply the background to article, but article doesn't have a height either. If you'd just like to critique my bad code habits and formatting, that's alright too :). The images' absences shouldn't be important, though they are in a 16:9 ratio, and I had this problem before adding any jquery. Thank you so much. Sorry if there's an issue with my post or how I've asked it, it's my first time asking a question on here.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#images").cycle({
        containerResize: false,
        slideResize: false,
        fit: 1
        });

        $('article').cycle({ 

        activePagerClass: 'activeSlide',
        containerResize: false,
        slideResize: false,
        fit: 1,
        timeout: 0, 
        speed:   300, 
        startingSlide:0,
        pager: "#buttons",
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        return '#buttons li:eq(' + idx + ')';}
        });


        $('#right').click(function() {
            $('article').cycle("next"); 
            return false; 
        }); 
        $('#left').click(function() { 
            $('article').cycle("prev"); 
            return false; 
        }); 
    });
    </script>
</head> 

<body>


    <div id="container">


            <div id="arrows">
                <div id="left">&#60;</div><div id="right">&#62;</div>
            </div>
            <nav>

                <ul id="buttons">
                    <li><a href="#"></a>
                    <li><a href="#"></a>
                    <li><a href="#"></a>
                    <li><a href="#"></a>
                    <li><a href="#"></a>
                </ul>

            </nav>
            <div class="fix"></div>
            <article>
                <section id="images">
                <img src="images/alaska.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"/>
                <img src="images/field.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"/>
                <img src="images/sunset.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"/>
                </section >
                <section id="about">
                <p>
                    my name is <span style="color:crimson">max</span>.<br>
                    i'm a senior in high school.<br>
                    i love <span style="color:yellow">code</span><br>
                    <span style="color:#a45bc4">&amp;</span><br>
                    i love <span style="color:lightgreen">design</span>.<br>
                    <span style="color:#a45bc4">welcome to my site.</span>
                </p>
                </section >
                <section id="work">

                </section >

                <section id="contact">

                </section>
                <section id="place">

                </section>

            </article>
            <div id="bottom"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-image:url("images/clouds.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-color:white;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:100%

}

#container{
    width:70%;
    min-height:103px;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-width:182px;
}

#arrows{
    max-width: 140px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    -moz-border-radius: 70px 70px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 70px 70px 0 0;
    border-radius: 70px 70px 0 0;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
    top:25px;
    z-index:100;
    border-top:1px solid;
    border-color:#cccccc;
    font-family:"Lato";
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:60px;
    font-size:68px;
    color:#cfcfcf;
    font-weight:100;
    font-stretch:ultra-condensed;

}

#right:hover, #left:hover{
    color:#a45bc4;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#right, #left{
    display:inline;
    color:#cfcfcf;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;       
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;

    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

}
nav{
    width:calc(100%-2px);
    border-left:1px solid #cfcfcf;
    border-right:1px solid #cfcfcf;
    height:35px;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    min-width:182px;


}
#buttons{
    position:relative;

    float:right;
    margin-right:6px;
    z-index:100;
}
.fix{
    clear:both;
}
.current{
    padding-right:0px;
}

#buttons li{

    display:inline-block;
    height:26px;
    width:26px;
    background-image:url("images/navc.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:24px;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-top:4px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#buttons li:hover{
    opacity:.8;

}
#buttons a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#buttons li.activeSlide{
    background-image:url("images/violetc.jpg");
    height:26px;
    width:26px;
    background-size:26px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}


article{
    width:100%;
    min-width:184px;
    height:100%;

}


section{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    color:white;
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:36px;
    font-family:"Lato";
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
p{

}
#about{

}

.option img{
    opacity:.6
}


.option:hover{
    opacity:.8;

}
#bottom{
    border-left:1px solid #cfcfcf;
    border-right:1px solid #cfcfcf;
    border-bottom:1px solid #cfcfcf;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    min-width:182px;
    margin-top:56.25%;


}


@media all and (max-width:690px){
    #buttons{
    margin-top:2px;
    width:98%;
    text-align:center;
    }
    nav{position:relative;
    text-align:center;}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce that issue. Possible to make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate?

Comment: The jsbin.com or fiddle would definitely help.

Comment: I'd love to, but I'm not sure what exactly I would put there...

Comment: here's a copy of the site, though: notice that when you inspect element, article height is 0px. [link](http://www.walkerspencer.com/chrhsweb/max)

Comment: article element is 0 height because it contains no children in the document flow. Floats aren't the only thing that takes children out of document flow, absolutely positioning children does that too. If you didn't add the inline style of position absolute on the children `section` elements, then it has to do with the slideshow script you're using.

Comment: Alright, I think I sort of understand. I'm still very new to web design, though. How can I fix this issue? Commenting out the jquery and mucking with my html a bit to compensate didn't really change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're keeping the slideshow plugin, and it is what's causing the absolutely positioned children (you're not doing it,) then your only option is to force the height of the `article` element, if you want to use it for something.

You can either apply a class/ID to it (if you're using other `article` elements that have nothing to do with this style, and you only use it once per page, then use an ID, or if you want to re-use it somewhere else on the same page, use a class.) So you would have something like:

```
article.slideshow-container { height: 498px; }
```

And you can then use it for whatever you want. This is a fixed-height though, so if image height changes, you lose out again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely with your implementation of the jQuery Cycle Plugin. As setek has mentioned, the slideshow makes your section divs position absolute, which collapses the height of the article element to 0. You can add the following to your cycle script to dynamically adjust the height for each slide/section:

```
    before : function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement){
      $('article').css('height', $(nextSlideElement).height()+'px');
    },
```

You should also clean up your code (it is a bit of a mess) and try to take things step by step. I have created a working example for you here:

http://jsfiddle.net/BCyD8/

You will have to work a bit to get the spacing right.